# How to retrieve objects based on primary key and another column in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I know how to retrieve an object by id:

```
MyObject.find(1)
```

I know how to retrieve objects by an arbitrary column:

```
MyObject.where(something: true)
```

I can combine the two conditions like this (assuming I haven't changed the name of the primary key from the default `id`):

```
MyObject.where(id: 1, something: true)
```

Is there a more elegant or idiomatic way of combining the two conditions (that would work even if the primary key had a different name)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can very well chain `.find` after a `.where` :

```
MyObject.where(something: true).find(id) # Add .joins etc. before the .find
```

Note that this **won't** trigger a second SQL request. This will just add an `AND` to the query's `WHERE`.

Comment: Thank you.  My guess is that this would be less efficient in my case, since the where would return lots of objects and would not benefit from an index, but this does satisfy the condition of not depending on a certain primary key name.

Comment: Have you checked the SQL generated ? The SQL statement is generated when you `.find`

Comment: Ven, thanks for the clarification.  I'm not sure what to put where you have ":a".

Comment: Erm, whatever you want to join -- it's just an example to show that's not forbidden. I'll edit it :). Feel free to mark as the answer.

Comment: You are absolutely right.  I tested the SQL generated.

I'm tempted not to mark this answer correct, because I think your 6666 reputation is so cool, but I'll do so anyway. ;-)

Comment: Don't worry - I've noticed it already and screen captured it :P.